# How do I remove the default options from an HTML file input?

Tags: hta, html-input

I'm making an HTML file input. This is what I have now:

```
<input type=file accept=".ctw" name=f>
```

The .ctw file is a custom extension I created for a game map file. I need to make the file input accept only the .ctw file, but for some reason the file input accepts HTML pages and images. How should I remove the extra options?

Comment: is snippet you provided exactly same as this one causing error?

Comment: There is not an error occurring in that snippet. I am trying to remove the extra options for opening a file.

Comment: You  can't entirely remove options for other file formats from the Open file dialog, they always will be available, as kind of basic alternatives.